# Why am I getting Your system schema version is -1

Tags: 8, database

I'm trying to make database updates to my Drupal 8 website, but I keep getting the error `Your system schema version is -1. Updating directly from a schema version prior to 8000 is not supported.`, therefore I can't make the updates. I already have the line `const CORE_MINIMUM_SCHEMA_VERSION = 8000;` in core/lib/Drupal.php. Why am I getting this error?

The full error is as below:

```
[error]  Your system schema version is -1. Updating directly from a schema version prior to 8000 is not supported. You must upgrade your site to Drupal 8 first, see https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/upgrade. (Currently using Minimum schema version The installed schema version does not meet the minimum.)

 Requirements check reports errors. Do you wish to continue? (yes/no) [yes]:
 >

 ------------------------- ----------------------------------------------- ------------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Module                    Update ID                                       Type          Description
 ------------------------- ----------------------------------------------- ------------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  address                   clear_country_list                              post-update   Clear caches to receive the new country list.
  address                   convert_names_subdivisions                      post-update   Re-save all entities with address data to update names and subdivisions.
  adminimal_admin_toolbar   avoid_custom_font                               post-update   Update adminimal_admin_toolbar.settings to include avoid_custom_font.
  block_content             add_views_reusable_filter                       post-update   Adds a 'reusable' filter to all Custom Block views.
  block                     disable_blocks_with_missing_contexts            post-update   Disable all blocks with missing context IDs in block_update_8001().
  block                     disabled_region_update                          post-update   Disable blocks that are placed into the "disabled" region.
  block                     fix_negate_in_conditions                        post-update   Fix invalid 'negate' values in block visibility conditions.
  comment                   enable_comment_admin_view                       post-update   Enable the comment admin view.
  commerce_cart             1                                               post-update   Revert Cart views to fix broken Price fields.
  commerce_cart             2                                               post-update   Revert the cart block and form views.
  commerce_checkout         1                                               post-update   Revert Checkout views to fix broken Price fields.
  commerce_log              1                                               post-update   Revert the Activity view to make the date column sortable.
  commerce_log              2                                               post-update   Revert the Activity view to change page limit and ordering.
  commerce_order            1                                               post-update   Revert Order views to fix broken Price fields.
  commerce_order            2                                               post-update   Update order types.
  commerce_order            3                                               post-update   Revert the Order and Profile entity view displays.
  commerce_order            4                                               post-update   Revert the Order entity view displays.
  commerce_order            5                                               post-update   Revert the Order entity form display.
  commerce_order            6                                               post-update   Update the profile address field.
  commerce_order            7                                               post-update   Revert the 'commerce_order_item_table' view - empty text added.
  commerce_order            8                                               post-update   Unlock the profile 'address' field.
  commerce_order            9                                               post-update   Grants the "manage order items" permission to roles that can update orders.
  commerce_payment          1                                               post-update   Re-save payment methods to populate the payment_gateway_mode field.
  commerce_payment          2                                               post-update   Re-save payments to populate the payment_gateway_mode and completed fields.
  commerce_product          1                                               post-update   Revert the Products view because of the updated permission.
  commerce_product          2                                               post-update   Revert the default order item form display.
  commerce_product          3                                               post-update   Revert the default order item form display.
  commerce_product          4                                               post-update   Expose the status field on every product form.
  commerce_product          5                                               post-update   Enable the "Duplicate" variation button for every product type.
  commerce_product          6                                               post-update   Grants the "manage variations" permission to roles that can update products.
  commerce_product          7                                               post-update   Move the variations form to its own tab.
  commerce_promotion        1                                               post-update   Add the coupons field to orders.
  commerce_promotion        2                                               post-update   Add the 'promotion_id' field to coupons.
  commerce_promotion        3                                               post-update   Delete orphaned coupons.
  commerce_promotion        4                                               post-update   Add the compatibility field to promotions.
  commerce_promotion        6                                               post-update   Update offers and conditions.
  commerce_promotion        7                                               post-update   Add the condition_operator field to promotions.
  commerce_promotion        8                                               post-update   Re-save promotions to populate the condition operator field.
  commerce_promotion        9                                               post-update   Update offers and conditions.
  commerce_store            1                                               post-update   Revert the Stores view because of the updated permission.
  commerce_store            2                                               post-update   Revert the Stores view.
  contextual                fixed_endpoint_and_markup                       post-update   Ensure new page loads use the updated JS and get the updated markup.
  dblog                     convert_recent_messages_to_view                 post-update   Replace 'Recent log messages' with a view.
  editor                    clear_cache_for_file_reference_filter           post-update   Clear the render cache to fix file references added by Editor.
  field                     email_widget_size_setting                       post-update   Adds the 'size' setting for email widgets.
  field                     entity_reference_handler_setting                post-update   Fixes the 'handler' setting for entity reference fields.
  field                     remove_handler_submit_setting                   post-update   Remove the stale 'handler_submit' setting for entity_reference fields.
  field                     save_custom_storage_property                    post-update   Re-save all field storage config objects to add 'custom_storage' property.
  image                     image_style_dependencies                        post-update   Saves the image style dependencies into form and view display entities.
  image                     scale_and_crop_effect_add_anchor                post-update   Add 'anchor' setting to 'Scale and crop' effects.
  language                  language_select_widget                          post-update   Add the 'include_locked' settings to the 'language_select' widget.
  locale                    clear_cache_for_old_translations                post-update   Clear cache to ensure plural translations are removed from it.
  node                      configure_status_field_widget                   post-update   Load all form displays for nodes, add status with these settings, save.
  node                      node_revision_views_data                        post-update   Clear caches due to updated views data.
  system                    add_region_to_entity_displays                   post-update   Update entity displays to contain the region for each field.
  system                    change_action_plugins                           post-update   Change plugin IDs of actions.
  system                    change_delete_action_plugins                    post-update   Change plugin IDs of delete actions.
  system                    classy_message_library                          post-update   Clear caches to ensure Classy's message library is always added.
  system                    extra_fields                                    post-update   Update all entity displays that contain extra fields.
  system                    field_formatter_entity_schema                   post-update   Clear caches due to schema changes in core.entity.schema.yml.
  system                    field_type_plugins                              post-update   Force field type plugin definitions to be cleared.   @see https:www.drupal.orgnode2403703
  system                    hashes_clear_cache                              post-update   Force caches using hashes to be cleared (Twig, render cache, etc.).
  system                    language_item_callback                          post-update   Force cache clear for language item callback.   @see https:www.drupal.orgnode2851736
  system                    recalculate_configuration_entity_dependencies   post-update   Re-save all configuration entities to recalculate dependencies.
  system                    states_clear_cache                              post-update   Force cache clear to ensure aggregated JavaScript files are regenerated.   @see https:www.drupal.orgprojectdrupalissues2995570
  system                    timestamp_plugins                               post-update   Force plugin definitions to be cleared.   @see https:www.drupal.orgnode2802663
  taxonomy                  clear_entity_bundle_field_definitions_cache     post-update   Clear entity_bundle_field_definitions cache for new parent field settings.
  taxonomy                  clear_views_data_cache                          post-update   Clear caches due to updated taxonomy entity views data.
  taxonomy                  handle_publishing_status_addition_in_views      post-update   Add a 'published' = TRUE filter for all Taxonomy term views and converts  existing ones that were using the 'content_translation_status' field.
  user                      enforce_order_of_permissions                    post-update   Enforce order of role permissions.
  views                     boolean_filter_values                           post-update   Set all boolean filter values to strings.
  views                     bulk_field_moved                                post-update   Update dependencies for moved bulk field plugin.
  views                     cleanup_duplicate_views_data                    post-update   Update some views fields that were previously duplicated.
  views                     entity_link_url                                 post-update   Add additional settings to the entity link field and convert node_path usage  to entity_link.
  views                     field_formatter_dependencies                    post-update   Include field formatter dependencies in a view when the formatter is used.
  views                     filter_placeholder_text                         post-update   Add placeholder settings to string or numeric filters.
  views                     grouped_filters                                 post-update   Rebuild caches to ensure schema changes are read in.
  views                     revision_metadata_fields                        post-update   Fix table names for revision metadata fields.   @see https:www.drupal.orgnode2831499
  views                     serializer_dependencies                         post-update   Fix views with serializer dependencies.
  views                     table_display_cache_max_age                     post-update   Fix cache max age for table displays.
  views                     taxonomy_index_tid                              post-update   Fix views with dependencies on taxonomy terms that don't exist.
  views                     update_cacheability_metadata                    post-update   Update the cacheability metadata for all views.
  views                     views_data_table_dependencies                   post-update   Include views data table provider in views dependencies.
 ------------------------- ----------------------------------------------- ------------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Do you wish to run the specified pending updates? (yes/no) [yes]:
 >

 [notice] Update started: address_post_update_clear_country_list
 [ok] Update completed: address_post_update_clear_country_list
 [notice] Update started: address_post_update_convert_names_subdivisions
 [ok] Update completed: address_post_update_convert_names_subdivisions
 [notice] Update started: adminimal_admin_toolbar_post_update_avoid_custom_font
 [ok] Update completed: adminimal_admin_toolbar_post_update_avoid_custom_font
 [notice] Update started: block_content_post_update_add_views_reusable_filter
 [ok] Update completed: block_content_post_update_add_views_reusable_filter
 [notice] Update started: block_post_update_disable_blocks_with_missing_contexts
 [ok] Update completed: block_post_update_disable_blocks_with_missing_contexts
 [notice] Update started: block_post_update_disabled_region_update
 [ok] Update completed: block_post_update_disabled_region_update
 [notice] Update started: block_post_update_fix_negate_in_conditions
 [ok] Update completed: block_post_update_fix_negate_in_conditions
 [notice] Update started: comment_post_update_enable_comment_admin_view
 [error]  'action' entity with ID 'comment_delete_action' already exists.
 [error]  Update failed: comment_post_update_enable_comment_admin_view
 [error]  Update aborted by: comment_post_update_enable_comment_admin_view
 [error]  Finished performing updates.
```

Comment: It means that the result of `drupal_get_installed_schema_version('system')` is -1. So in your config, the system module is designated as being version -1, instead of the expected 8000 or greater.

Comment: How can I verify this?

Comment: Inspect the result of that line of code

Comment: What is `system` in this context? I don't have such a table.

Comment: Why is it returning -1? It's blocking updates.

Comment: @NoSssweat I don't have that table anywhere. Drupal 8 doesn't have that table as far as I know.

Comment: It's in config not a table any more. You can get it via `drush cget core.extension module`. There's no logical reason it would be -1, unless the original installation failed in some way, or someone/something has manually edited the value. If you want to know what happened, you'll have to go back over backups/git logs etc

Comment: Is there a way to revert this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reset it with Drush

`drush ev drupal_set_installed_schema_version('system', 8000)`

OR

If you have [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) installed with, you can execute the following PHP Code

```
drupal_set_installed_schema_version('system', 8000);
```

Comment: Careful, unless you’re going from 8.0 that’s likely to cause a lot of errors. OP needs to determine the correct schema version to update the config to, based on what version they’ve upgraded from. Otherwise you’ll be running a lot of updates that have already run

Comment: It was because I truncated key_value table due to getting duplicates when running my custom code.